# How do I automatically replace/reject a pending release with a newer one?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline that is automatically building and deploying code to my staging environment. For my production environment I have a pre-deployment manual approval gate so that only releases that have gone through some review will go out to customers. So far so good.

The problem is that as new releases go out to the staging environment there is a growing list of releases that are now queued for this manual approval. In order to release the most recent version I need to go and manually reject each of the intermediate releases. This has become a laborious process.

I would like to automatically reject the production deploy of the previous release every time a new release goes to staging.

I've looked at the MS docs, SO, the pipeline settings, the available pipeline release tasks and can't find a way to do this.

Release History showing old release queued for approval:

[image: Release History showing old release queued for approval]

Comment: Gonna answer my own question here...
Looks like there is a magic checkbox in the Deployment Settings area.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#queuing-policies

Comment: If you found your own answer, post it below and accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like this behavior can be controlled by making a change in  the Deployment Queue Settings area. Switching to "Deploy latest and cancel the others" will automatically cancel the previously queued release and queue the newer one. If you have Slack integration turned on (as I do) you will see a cancellation message.

So long as your process is simple enough that you know when new builds are being made, this feels like good behavior. It gives you a basic manual gate without adding any other overhead.

There is more documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#queuing-policies

[Deployment Queue Setting: subsequent releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbu7A.png)

Comment: @MattWebster I can't seem to get this working for me. I have changed the setting in the pipeline but it is not cancelling the releases with pending approval actions.

Comment: Same behaviour as @billoverton here. It looks like this flag will make the queue skip any intermediate queued deployment but will not cancel active gate. At least, it makes a 100 entries queue restartable with the latest one with a single cancellation intead of 101. It is unfortunate though...